# Merge conflict issue - wrong file selected after merge

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, git-checkout, git-merge-conflict

I'm having an issue with merging in git. I'm no git expert.
I have two branches feature_branch and develop. Develop being a public branch.
I have made some changes in feature_branch and I have created a MR and I'm getting a conflict.
When resolving a merge I cannot make it use the file version from feature_branch.

```
> git checkout feature_branch
> git merge develop

Auto-merging script_new_name.sh
CONFLICT (rename/delete): script_old_name.sh deleted in HEAD and renamed to script_new_name.sh in develop. Version develop of script_new_name.sh left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

> git mergetool
Merging:
script_new_name.sh

Deleted merge conflict for 'script_new_name.sh':
  {local}: deleted
  {remote}: created file
Use (c)reated or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort?
```

Whatever I choose, either the file gets deleted or the version from develop is taken. I would like to keep the version of the file that is on the feature_branch. How can I do that?

Thanks for support!

Comment: From the conflict's message : on `feature_branch`, `script_old_name.sh` has been deleted and `script_new_name.sh` doesn't exist. Can you describe which is the file you want to keep from `feature_branch` ?

Comment: Because this starts with `git checkout feature_branch`, `feature_branch` *is* `HEAD`. As @LeGEC noted, the error message implies that there is no version of `script_new_name.sh` in `feature_branch`. To keep the lack of a file, delete the file; to keep a modified and/or renamed file, don't delete the file.

Comment: That's the issue script_new_name.sh exists in feature branch and it has been updated wrt develop branch.

Answer (score 0):

Given that git left the file in the working tree, all you have to do is add it:

```
git add script_new_name.sh
git merge --continue
```

That should keep the file without issues. You should wonder *why* the file was deleted in one branch, though. Was it just deleted? Was it *moved*? If it was moved, a little more brain power will be required to fihure out what the right move would be. But if the ultimate conflict resolution in this case is to keep the file with the original file name, then that recipe should work.